# What is wrong with this fortran code using pointer aliases

Tags: pointers, fortran, gfortran, intel-fortran

The example consists of two files

`md_ptr.f90` :

```
 module md_ptr

implicit none

public

type test_data
   real :: x, y(3), z(2) , dx, dy, dz
   integer :: ii , jj , kk 
   real :: res
end type

type(test_data), allocatable, target :: dat(:)
real, pointer :: res(:)


contains

subroutine alloc(n)
implicit none

integer, intent(in) :: n

allocate(dat(n))

res => dat(:)%res

res(1:2) = 112312.12 !  for debugging!



end subroutine


subroutine call_alloc(n)
implicit none

integer, intent(in) :: n
call alloc(n)
end subroutine 

end module
```

The second file `test_ptr.f90`

```
program testpointer

use md_ptr

implicit none 

call call_alloc(100)

write(*,*) res(1:2), dat(1:2)% res

end program
```

Compiling this with gfortran version 9.3.0:

```
gfortran -c md_ptr.f90 test_ptr.f90; gfortran md_ptr.o test_ptr.o
```

Now when running I get following output:

```
112312.117       0.00000000       112312.117       112312.117
```

As you can see the second output of the pointer alias `res` is not correct!

Now, if i replace `gfortran` with `ifort` I get the expected output:

```
 112312.117       112312.117       112312.117       112312.117
```

**UPDATE
Also tested with `gfortran` 10.1.0 with similar outcome as version 9.3.0
Tested with Cray compiler which did indeed produce the expected outcome as with ifort

Comment: You should always try to write up a [minimal working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). This way everybody can try the code themselves. I am quite sure that this line `residual => varprop% residual` is not standard Fortran. Here `residual` is a scalar pointer whereas `varprop` is a 1d array?!

Comment: @jack . I tried to write a minimal example. But seems to work, not sure if the example is simple that the compiler deduces everything easily. 

Yes, `varprop% residual` is an array and I am trying to point a pointer to that array. I have edited my `residual` pointer. That is how I declare: `real, pointer :: residual(:)`

Comment: `varprop(:)% residual` is the shape of the array. Is it problematic because I am using Array of structure and the variable `varprop(:)% residual` is not contigious. ? I have read that Fortran can handle such things?

Comment: Have you tried with a newer gfortran version?

Comment: I am using  v9.3.0 which is quite new ( 1 year old.), and the stuff I am using is 90/95 Fortran?

Comment: If I change the write statement to `write(*,*) res`
`write(*,*) dat % res` I get the expected answer in gfortran 10.3

Comment: by writing two commands instead? Why would that change anything?

Comment: Unreported compiler bugs typically go unfixed.

Comment: As Steve is strongly hinting this looks like a compiler bug - best thing would be to report it as such.

Comment: @M.S.B. I tried your suggestion and this does not work. I tried both on gfortran 9.3 and 10.1

Comment: I have reported this to gcc-bugs@gcc.gnu.org